# Jinja2 unescaping the sequence

Tags: jinja2, jinja2-cli, jinjava

I am working on a jinja2 template in python where autoescape=true flag is required due to privacy constraint.
Since the autoescaping is enabled, jinja template ouputs the ascii value i.e `&gt;&gt;` instead of `>>` symbols.

Is their a way where I can still output the `>` sign while still enabling the autoescape flag?

item: `abcd >> efgh`

Sample Jinja2 template:

```
{{ item }}
```

Current output: `abcd &gt;&gt; efgh`

Expected output: `abcd >> efgh`

Expected output: `abcd >> efgh`

Answer (score 0):

You can manually mark a specific variable as safe with the [`safe` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping):

```
{{ item|safe }}
```

But then you need to make sure that `item` does not contain any harmful content (replace them manually).